# Is there such thing as an EMG sensor which doesn't use electrodes?

Tags: sensor, sensing

In a traditional EMG the user is required to clean the target area with alcohol, then apply some gel, and finally stick on an electrode.

I'm looking for some sensor that can read the same muscle tension/activation data without that extensive setup. Something that would work just by being vaguely/imperfectly in contact with the skin, and could be embedded inside a haptic VR suit.

I need to read the muscle activations of over 40 muscles simultaneously, and at 2-3 electrodes required per muscle it would be highly infeasible to ask the player to apply 100+ electrodes to their body every time they want to play a game.

Comment: Position/motion sensors make more sense to me in this sort of application.

Comment: I can't use position. I don't want the player to be given preferential treatment by the physics engine. Every movement must be checked against physics. In traditional full-body tracking the position is the infallible oracle and the game must respect it. That means enemies are powerless if they try to block your arm because your arm HAS to be at that position in the game. If an enemy were to try to topple you over they'd fail or else the game would de-sync. That is not even to begin to mention what happens if you try a kong vault or flying armbar on thin air.

Comment: You need to compute acceleration , velocity , momentum and inertia to determine the reaction to any similar a,v,x ,p and direction vectors of each to get true physics and muscle amplitude won’t do that! Even with perfect electrodes. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Why would I need anything more than muscle amplitude? Muscle amplitude is the input. Acceleration, velocity, momentum and inertia should be derived, computed within the physics engine of the game, not measured from real-life events. When you activate a muscle it should move an in-game part of your body and the resulting acceleration should depend on how massive it is in the game. In real life the player is strapped to a chair. Does that make sense? Nothing impossible about it, other than the fact the player will have great difficulty balancing due to the lack of inner-ear feedback

Comment: @pete - I saw your earlier question and I see where you are going with this - the answer in my opinion is to use force feedback to restrict motion when physics dictate. Position sensors should work in that scenario.

Comment: You mean like an "exosuit" thing right? I fear those might be even harder to engineer and take an immense amount of time, given all the moving parts which create many possible points of failure. It is also very difficult to make a suit compact and wireless enough to not disturb the player during maneuvers such as a triangle choke or spinning back kick. Based on the Youtube videos I've seen, current prototypes can't even allow the player to sit/lay down yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the electrodes are also capacitors and any loose fitting varies the capacitance from pressure of the electrode. When there is a galvanic charge on your skin electrode interface modulating the capacitance also modulates the voltage.To avoid the skin motion noise from modulating the galvanic charge , I believe the resistance must be much less than the capacitive Impedance change at the surface

. Thus silver oxide pads are preferred or thin sticky gel.

The impedance of each electrode must low compared to body to air impedance and fairly equal in order for good CM line voltage balanced differential CMRR rejection.  Why ? The body surface acts as a dielectric antenna for stray line voltage. Nothing is absorbed except it interferes with your CMRR of high gain high impedance differential amp or INA.